# Bug: "Migrated from guitars" link goes to Guitars, which redirects to the wrong Music question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, content-import, hyperlinks

The link that appears below each imported question does bad things.

[image: picture]

For example, look at this imported question: [What's the difference between the "smooth" strings and the "rough" strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/997/whats-the-difference-between-the-smooth-strings-and-the-rough-strings)

The guitars.stackexchange.com link goes to [this address](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/540/whats-the-difference-between-the-smooth-strings-and-the-rough-strings?noredirect=1):

```
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/540/whats-the-difference-between-the-smooth-strings-and-the-rough-strings?noredirect=1
```

Despite the "noredirect", it redirects.  It redirects to [an answer with ID 540 on this site](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-is-a-good-software-that-allows-on-the-fly-looping/540):

```
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-is-a-good-software-that-allows-on-the-fly-looping/540#540
```

This is obviously unintended, and due to the fact that the migrated-from site no longer exists.

Comment: It's inconsistent, too--sometimes it redirects to the answer with the ID in question, but it will also on occasion redirect to the question with the ID in question.

Comment: @NReilingh That's because all posts (questions+answers) are numbered sequentially, they don't have separate ID sets. It just goes to the post with the right ID, whether it's a question or an answer.

Comment: Aha, I was wondering about that. Makes sense.

Comment: This is the bug i was trying to highlight here that you closed as a duplicate http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/211/internal-links-from-guitars-se-are-broken

Comment: @DRL You were highlighting links that were editable (like in questions and answers) and didn't seem to mention the migration links. That's what this is about, since we can't edit those. If you had noticed something that wasn't covered in the linked duplicate, you could have elaborated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've gone through and cleared the migration history on these - they don't serve a purpose anymore.